# Jenkins not finding JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, jenkins

Trying to paste where I have the Java JDK installed, but Jenkins keeps saying:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin doesn’t look like a JDK directory
```

Also tried `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin\java` and got:

```
not a directory on the Jenkins master (but perhaps it exists on some slaves)
```

Anyone what the last folder/file should be?  I am assuming bin\java but that is giving me trouble.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` should be pointed to parent directory of `bin` not to the `bin`

Comment: Added it as an answer

Comment: still doens't work after pointing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`JAVA_HOME` should be pointed to parent of `bin`

Answer (score 3):

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
```

This is what worked in my case.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's because the path you mentioned is different from what Jenkins has stored.
Go to Manage Jenkins-> System Information->Environment Variables
You can see JAVA_HOME copy the path and save it.
Issue will be resolved