# Error in Maven Install & Maven Build

Tags: java, maven

When I do the Mave Install and Build it shows an error.

```
    Maven Install
   ================

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] parent
[INFO] KMS DAO
[INFO] ABSTRACT ECM SERVICES
[INFO] ECM SERVICES
[INFO] KMS SERVICES
[INFO] WORKFLOW WEB
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building parent 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ KMS-PARENT ---
[INFO] Installing D:\Work_Space\Shamila_ACDR_1.2\KMS-PARENT\pom.xml to C:\Users\Sharmila\.m2\repository\com\shamila\KMS-PARENT\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\KMS-PARENT-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building KMS DAO 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ KMS-DAO ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ KMS-DAO ---
[INFO] Compiling 179 source files to D:\Work_Space\Shamila_ACDR_1.2\KMS-PARENT\KMS-DAO\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] parent ............................................ SUCCESS [1.060s]
[INFO] KMS DAO ........................................... FAILURE [2.077s]
[INFO] ABSTRACT ECM SERVICES ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ECM SERVICES ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] KMS SERVICES ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WORKFLOW WEB ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.616s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 12 12:16:34 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile  (default-compile) on project KMS-DAO: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\..\lib\tools.jar
[ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
[ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
[ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
[ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :KMS-DAO
```

Also same thing happen to maven build.

```
      Maven Build
   ==================

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] parent
[INFO] KMS DAO
[INFO] ABSTRACT ECM SERVICES
[INFO] ECM SERVICES
[INFO] KMS SERVICES
[INFO] WORKFLOW WEB
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building parent 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building KMS DAO 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ KMS-DAO ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ KMS-DAO ---
[INFO] Compiling 179 source files to D:\Work_Space\Shamila_ACDR_1.2\KMS-PARENT\KMS-DAO\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] parent ............................................ SUCCESS [0.317s]
[INFO] KMS DAO ........................................... FAILURE [2.066s]
[INFO] ABSTRACT ECM SERVICES ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ECM SERVICES ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] KMS SERVICES ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WORKFLOW WEB ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.105s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 12 12:24:12 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile   (default-compile) on project KMS-DAO: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\..\lib\tools.jar
[ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
[ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
[ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
[ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :KMS-DAO
```

I did all the suggested solutions for this by changing the Setting.xml and changing the JAVA-HOME. Also I'm using JDK 1.6. But I couldn't find a solution.

Thank You.

Comment: what is the JAVA_HOME variable which you have set?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build failed question - maven - jre or jdk problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222560/build-failed-question-maven-jre-or-jdk-problem)

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45 this is the value of my JAVA_HOME.

Comment: I got the solution with your help. Thanks  piet.t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to set `JAVA_HOME` properly to the root directory of JDK - [that is it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974725/jenkins-not-finding-java-home)